# change the source code online

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I'm trying to allow my client to change all paragraph content by visiting the page, i.e. in pure WYSIWYG mode.

For example clicking on first paragraph he will add `green` before the existing content.

```
<p>123</p>
<p>456</p>
<p>789</p>
```

js

```
 $("p").attr('contenteditable', true);

$("#btnsave").click(function() {
    var a = `currentParagraph.newContent`;
console.log(a) //I need `green 123` here
});
```

How to get edited content as a variable ?

Also, for changing the server source code I will send the new content using php-jquery ajax code, but how to tell the server on which paragraph the new content should be applied ?

Any help?

Comment: you tagged as php with no code to support the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `input` event attached to `p` elements,  `.index()`, `$.post()`

```js
var curr = null; 

$("p").attr('contenteditable', true).on("input", function() {
   curr = $(this).index() -1
 })

$("#btnsave").click(function() {
    var a = $("p").eq(curr).text();
    console.log(a, $("div").html()); //I need `green 123` here
    // post `p` elements to server
    // $.post("/path/to/server", {data:$("div").html()})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
<p>123</p>
<p>456</p>
<p>789</p>
  </div>
<button id="btnsave">click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see the first part very well, but, please explain (or write a code) how to tell the server on which paragraph the new content should be applied ?

Comment: `curr` variable is index of last edited `p` element. Though, since `button` can be clicked at any time , for example, after all `p` elements `html` have been changed, approach at `js` above would be to send `html` of all `p` elements to server